# Convert millisecond String to Date in Java

Tags: java, string, date

i have a String x = "1086073200000" . This is basically millisecond which I need to convert to a Date.

To convert i am using

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

long tempo1=Long.parseLong(x);
System.out.println(tempo1);  // output is 86073200000 instead of the whole thing
long milliSeconds=1346482800000L;

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
System.out.println(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

The problem is when i convert the string x to long , some digits go away due to the limit on the size of long.

How do I preserve the entire String.

THanks.

Comment: So your code doesn't relate to the question at all? - you don't show the string to long conversion you claim is causing problems...

Comment: @John3136: He's converting the long (milliseconds) into a date and trying to print it "long -> string".

Comment: @John3136,&Borleader I am reading a file,so input is String , which i need to convert to long so that I can convert it to date.

Comment: So why are you using `Double.parseDouble()`?

Comment: Can you post the file reading part? Your code is perfectly fine, the problem must be in the `String` that you are reading.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

> ```
> double tempo=Double.parseDouble(z);
> ```

Why are you parsing your `String` which is supposed to be a `Long` as a `Double`?

Try using `Long.parseLong`:

```
String x = "1086073200000"

DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

long milliSeconds= Long.parseLong(x);
System.out.println(milliSeconds);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(milliSeconds);
System.out.println(formatter.format(calendar.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 9):

I tried this code and it worked for me

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String x = "1086073200000";
    long foo = Long.parseLong(x);
    System.out.println(x + "\n" + foo);

    Date date = new Date(foo);
    DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    System.out.println(formatter.format(date)); 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli ( 1_346_482_800_000L );
```

> 2012-09-01T07:00:00Z

## Details

The [accepted answer by Tim Bender](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12504608/642706) and [other answer by enTropy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12504628/642706) are both correct. You were parsing your input string as a `double` rather than as a `long`.

## java.time

Also, the Question and Answers are using old outmoded date-time classes. These are now supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) package. See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). Much of the java.time functionality has been back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

### Count from epoch

The java.time classes count from the same [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) as the old classes, first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). So we can start the same way, with parsing the input as a `long`.

```
String input = "1086073200000";
long millis = Long.parseLong ( input );
```

### UTC

Use that `long` number to get an [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object. This class represents a moment on the time line in UTC, similar in concept to the old `java.util.Date`. But the new classes have a resolution up to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) whereas the old are limited to [milliseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond). Fortunately the `Instant` class has a convenient factory method taking a count of milliseconds-since-epoch, [`ofEpochMilli`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#ofEpochMilli-long-).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli ( millis );
```

### Time zone

Now assign a time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) object. This is similar in concept to a `java.util.Calendar` in that it represents a moment on the timeline with a specific assigned time zone.

Always specify the desired/expected time zone. Though optional, never omit the time zone as you did in your use of `Calendar` in the Question. If omitted, the JVM’s current default time zone is silently applied. This default can vary from machine to machine, and from time to time, even *during* runtime(!). Better to specify than assume.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of ( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant ( instant , zoneId );
```

Dump to console. Notice how the hour-of-day is `07` in UTC but `03` in Québec time as that zone had an offset of `-04:00`, four hours behind UTC, during the summer under [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time).

```
System.out.println ( "input: " + input + " | millis: " + millis + " | instant: " + instant + " | zdt: " + zdt );
```

> input: 1086073200000 | millis: 1086073200000 | instant: 2004-06-01T07:00:00Z | zdt: 2004-06-01T03:00-04:00[America/Montreal]

### A String is not a date-time

> How do I preserve the entire String.

Do not confuse a String of text describing the value of a date-time with the date-time itself. A date-time object can *generate* a String to represent its value, but that String is separate and distinct from the date-time object.

To generate a String from a java.time object such as `ZonedDateTime`, either:

- Call [`toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#toString--) to get a String in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.
  (as seen in example code above)
- Use [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) to:
  (a) Define your own custom format, or
  (b) Automatically localize to the user’s human language and cultural norms.

Search Stack Overflow for many other Questions and Answers on generating formatted Strings from `DateTimeFormatter`.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 4):

```
Date date = new Date(milliseconds);
```

Comment: Date constructor is deprecated

Answer (score 0):

Just do this ::::

```
import java.util.Date;

class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String str = "1346482800000";
        Long tmStmp = Long.parseLong(str);
        Date date = new Date(tmStmp);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

Comment: One, just avoid the `Date` class altogether, it’s poorly designed and long outdated. Use `java.time.Instant` as shown in the answer by Basil Bourque. Two, what you say is already in the two topmost answers.