# Excel date automatically converted into number this number again convert in Java date

Tags: java, excel, date, numbers

I have some data in Excel and I have to import in the database using Java but my date is automatically converted into a number but I have to save it as a date.

Comment: Search Stack Overflow before posting. If not yet covered, post details. Link to documentation. Give examples of inputs and outputs.

Comment: @BasilBourque i had already searched on stack overflow but i din't get proper answer so if you know kindly provide me solution for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the date that you are getting in java is essentially `long timeInMillis`, just convert that long value to date, refer [Convert millisecond String to Date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504537/convert-millisecond-string-to-date-in-java)

Comment: No actually  got date in just 5 digit.

Comment: provide snippet that and the output as well