# How can you check if a given time in milliseconds was yesterday?

Tags: java

Given a time in milliseconds, how can you check if it was yesterday?

Comment: 23:39 is not millis!

Comment: In which time zone? It’s never the same date in all time zones.

Comment: Possible near-duplicate of [How to check if a date Object equals yesterday?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006150/how-to-check-if-a-date-object-equals-yesterday)

Comment: Your Question is not clear. Rewrite with more explanation, perhaps with some examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would first convert the millis to a `Date` or `LocalDate` and then run the comparison.

Here's a quick example:

```
import java.time.*;


class DateCheckSample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Our input date
        long millis = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // Convert the millis to a LocalDate
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(millis);
        LocalDate inputDate = instant.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate();

        // Grab today's date
        LocalDate todaysDate = LocalDate.now();

        System.out.println(millis);

        // Check if date is yesterday
        if (todaysDate.minusDays(1).equals(inputDate)) {
            System.out.println(inputDate + " was yesterday!");
        } else {
            System.out.println(inputDate + " was NOT yeseterday!");
        }
    }
}
```

---

**The Result:**

```
2019-02-16 was NOT yesterday!
```

If you'd like to confirm it's working, just subtract `100000000` from `millis` before running.

> **Side Note:** As pointed out in the comments on your question, `23:59` is **not** a millis value...

Comment: 1550264167854
2019-02-15 was NOT yeseterday!

Comment: @Dr.Bright - I am confused by your comment. Are you saying that the output is wrong? It is 2019-02-16 in your time zone right now?

Comment: Good answer, except for that call to `toLocalDateTime`. Unnecessary. And illogical as converting to `LocalDateTime` discards all time zone infirmation.

Comment: I suggest breaking up your code to multiple lines, to make the `ZonedDateTime` obvious.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/Date.html), you can simply use the [modulus operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/90238/whats-the-syntax-for-mod-in-java) with a bit of clever arithmetics. [`System#currentTimeMillis`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()) returns the amount of milliseconds that have passed since January 1, 1970, midnight (00:00).

Combining this with the number of milliseconds in a day (86,400,000), we can figure the time at which the last start of day was — which is when *today* began. Then we can see if the time given to us is smaller or larger than that value.

```
boolean isToday(long milliseconds) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long todayStart = now - (now % 86400000);
    if(milliseconds >= todayStart) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

To check if a time is *yesterday* instead of today, we simply check if it is between the start of today and the start of yesterday.

```
boolean isYesterday(long milliseconds) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long todayStart = now - (now % 86400000);
    long yesterdayStart = todayStart - 86400000;
    if(milliseconds >= yesterdayStart && < todayStart) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: But he wants to check if its yesterday :P Its clever. We can check that too.

Comment: @uneq95 I realized that just after I posted, hah.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the milliseconds to `Date` and then compare the day with today's `Date`.

For reference: [Convert millisecond String to Date in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12504537/convert-millisecond-string-to-date-in-java)

Comment: But i want: 8:25 PM (today) minus 8:26h is yesterday, how to check this?

Comment: You need to have the date as well with you. Otherwise you cant check just by comparing the times

Comment: The terrible `Date` class was supplanted years ago by `java.time.Instant`. No need to ever use `Date` again.

Comment: I was just telling the approach.